# Realm backlink like a foreign key

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

I am trying to find a way to insert a child object in its parent object without having to do a query for each one.
Let me be more specific:

```
class Parent extends RealmObject {
   String id;
   RealmList<Child> childs;
}
class Child extends RealmObject {
   String parentId;
}
```

And suppose I make a request in a webservice to get child object of different parents... so, now I have:

```
List<Child> childsOfDifferentParents;
```

And I want to add to link each child to its correct parent.

The only way I've found so far was, query for each parent and add it.
But, since it is too many objects, it wouldn't be efficient. What should I do?

Comment: For each child, query the parent and add it; maybe put them in a `Map<String, Parent` so that you don't query it twice (although depending on number of elements, that is also a bad idea)

Comment: that's exactly what I was trying to avoid when I said `query for each parent and add it.` :( , it is many objects.

Comment: That would be the only way of doing it. On the upside, you only have to do it once unlike SQLite where you would have to combine child and parent on each query for them.

Comment: :/ understood. thanks!